# Given a unitary $A$ and diagonal matrix $D$, find $B$ so that $AD=DB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In principle the title says it all. Given some diagonal Matrix $D$ (which may have 0 and repeated entries) and some unitary matrix $A$, I want to find some other unitary matrix $B$ so that $AD=DB$. What are the conditions that such a matrix $B$ exists and how can I construct it?

Comment: Typically this won't work. For example, when $D$ is invertible, you'd have to try $B=D^{-1}AD$, but this need not be unitary.

Comment: Cross-posted on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4459152/given-a-unitary-a-and-diagonal-matrix-d-find-b-so-that-ad-db

Answer (score 2):

If $D$ is invertible (i.e. has no zeroes on the diagonal), then $AD=D\cdot(D^{-1}AD)$. So $B=D^{-1}AD$ and it is unitary if, for example, $D$ itself is a scalar multiple of a diagonal unitary matrix (i.e. all of its diagonal entries have the same absolute value). But also in some other cases, say, when $A$ and $D$ commute.

If $D$ is not invertible, say, $D_{kk}=0$, then the $k$-th column of $AD$ is zero, and $k$-th row of $DB$ is zero. So for the equality $AD=DB$ to hold one must have $A_{kj}D_{jj}=0$ for all $j$ (and also $D_{jj}B_{jk}=0$). This means that whenever $D_{jj}\neq0$, one has $A_{k,j}=0$. So if (up to reordering) $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_s,0,\ldots,0)$, $A$ must be block-diagonal with an $s\times s$ block and an $(n-s)\times(n-s)$ block (here $n$ is the size of the matrices), and the block are unitary. The first block is subject to the same restrictions as in the case $D$ is invertible, while the second one is arbitrary, and one can find $B$ as a block-diagonal matrix with the same structure (the first block is calculated as above, the second one is arbitrary).